# No output when using void function

Tags: c++, function, output, reverse, void

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverse() {
  int reversedDigit = 0.0;
  int remainder;
  int num = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    remainder = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    reversedDigit = (reversedDigit * 10) + remainder;
    return;
  }
}

int main () {
  int num;
  cout << "Enter a number:";
  cin >> num;

  reverse();
  return 0;
}
```

I need to take an input `int` and then print it out in reverse by using a void function. For some reason, I can't get anything to output. It seems like the function isn't being recognized by the main.

Comment: `cout` is used to output. Where do you use `cout` in your `reverse` function?

Comment: For the assignment we aren't allowed to print the output inside the function

Comment: @ZacharyCorrente Then you have to pass a parameter by reference to collect the results, and print them after they've been collected inside of the function.

Comment: Zachary Corrente, Review the need for `return;` inside the loop.

Comment: You will need either two thing: add a return value, making it a int function, or using globals. I would try the return value if I were you.

Comment: Immediately after declaring `int num=0;`, the odds of `while (num>0)` being true are very, very poor.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Better always avoid global scope and use function parameters.

You need to pass input and accept output, so you need to use two parameters for `reverse` function. For the sake of example, let's call them `input` and `output`.
Input can be passed straight away, while output needs to be passed by reference, so function can modify it's original value.

Following example adds 2 to input and outputs result:

```
void doWork(int input, int &output)
{
  output = input + 2;
}

int main()
{
  int input = 0;
  int output = 0;

  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> input;

  doWork(input, output);

  cout << "Result: " << output;

  return 0;
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER (using global scope):

First of all:
You are declaring `int num` inside `main`, so it is not accessible by `reverse`. Declare `int num` in global scope (more about global scope below).

Second:
Since you're not allowed to print from function `reverse`, you're going to need global variables. Declare `int reversedDigit` outside any functions, just above `void reverse`, initialize it by 0 to avoid undefined behavior, and remove existing one from function `reverse`. This will make variable globally accessible to file scope. Then in reverse function, you can change value of this variable and print it out from main after calling reverse.

Example code (adds 2 to input and outputs result):

```
int input = 0;
int output = 0;

void doWork()
{
  output = input + 2;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter number: ";
  cin >> input;

  doWork();

  cout << "Result: " << output;
}
```

Comment: I think that all this advice to use global variables is misplaced.

Comment: Considering his requirements, it's only possible way to get his assignment done. He could also pass pointer to output variable and change it inside function, but I think he is far away from pointers for now. Otherwise I totally agree with you.

Comment: That is not true.  Functions can have parameters and return values.

Comment: Edited comment. He's only allowed to use void here.

Comment: OK (silly restriction, but hey); it's not obvious what a 'void function' actually means, but you can still return a value in a parameter passed by reference.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I'll change answer a bit.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reversedDigit = 0;
int num = 0;
void reverse()
{
    
      int remainder;
      while (num > 0){
      
      remainder = num % 10;
      num = num / 10;

      reversedDigit = (reversedDigit * 10) + remainder;
    }
    cout << reversedDigit << endl;
}


int main ()
{

  cout << "Enter a number:";
  cin >> num;

  reverse();

}
```

Comment: I got it everyone thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't use global variables when function parameters and return values will do. Global variables will make your code very difficult to fix and reason about.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is scope, function and main methods scopes are different you need to cin>> number; inside the reverse function that will solve your problem

```
void reverse(){
  int num;
  cout << "Enter a number:";
  cin >> num;
  int reversedDigit = 0.0;
  int remainder;
  
  while (num > 0){ 
     remainder = num % 10;
     num = num / 10;
     reversedDigit = (reversedDigit * 10) + remainder;        
  }
  cout << reversedDigit;
}
```